# Why kivy is not updating the position of widgets when pos_hint is changed Programmatically?

Tags: python, widget, kivy, kivy-language

I want to build a screen where on following button press changes happens on label's size and position:

```
Button : Changes
x++   -> x co-ordinate of label increments by 0.1 in pos_hint property
x--   -> x co-ordinate of label decrements by 0.1 in pos_hint property
```

So far I have tried this,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



class Screen(Widget):
    lbl = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count_x = 0.1

    def print_pos_change(self,instance,value):
        print(instance,"Moved to", value)

    def callback(self,arg):
        if arg == "x++":
            self.count_x+=0.1
            self.lbl.pos_hint["x"] = self.count_x
        elif arg == "x--":
            self.count_x-=0.1
            self.lbl.pos_hint["x"] = self.count_x

class WidgetEx(App):
    kv_directory = "kv-files"

    def build(self):
        return Screen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    WidgetEx().run()
```

Here is the kv file,

```
<Screen>
    lbl:lbl
    FloatLayout:
        size:root.width,root.height
        Label:
            id:lbl
            text:"Hello"
            size_hint:0.5,0.5
            on_pos:root.print_pos_change(self,self.pos)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            size_hint:1,0.1
            Button:
                text:"x++"
                on_press:root.callback("x++")
            Button:
                text:"x--"
                on_press:root.callback("x--")
```

Now problem here is neither position is not changing nor `print_pos_change` is called during change.

I know i can directly use `self.lbl.x` and `self.lbl.y` but i want to change it using `self.lbl.pos_hint`. How do i do that???

Here is ss of the UI,
 [image: Image of UI]

I have used `do_layout()` for `floatlayout` at end of method `callback` but buttons are also now moving with labels??How do i fix this?

Why size_hint is working properly and pos_hint don't??Is there any logic behind it?

I want to increment `pos_hint["x"]` property to increment by 0.1 at every `x++` button press.

Comment: can you make the smallest runnable example you can think of for this. Just one button and one label that only moves in one direction. Only the main issue is neccecary. Not the whole program, since its irrelevant and just more code and images to look through that doesnt contain your main issue. Just a suggestion for quicker help.

Comment: @el3ien I have reduced it to 2 buttons that concerns to ```pos_hint```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.
Try use numeric property on the pos hint right and top.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """

MyWidget:
    FloatLayout:
        size:root.width,root.height
        Label:
            text:"Hello"
            size_hint:0.5,0.5
            pos_hint: {"top":root.pos_hint_top, "right":root.pos_hint_right}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            size_hint:1,0.1
            Button:
                text:"x++"
                on_press:root.callback("x++")
            Button:
                text:"x--"
                on_press:root.callback("x--")

"""

class MyWidget(Widget):
    pos_hint_right = NumericProperty(0.5)
    pos_hint_top = NumericProperty(0.5)

    def callback(self,arg):
        if arg == "x++":
            self.pos_hint_right += 0.1
        elif arg == "x--":
            self.pos_hint_right -= 0.1

class WidgetEx(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    WidgetEx().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this thing. It works. I may ask from where you have learned kivy?? Any good tutorials or handbook?? I have searched youtube but not finding whole tutorials on kivy..

Comment: You are wellcome. I think I mostly used the api reference. But there are some good resources. Like https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki One good youtube series in there is https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq